# How to set cookie from Flask web server

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, flask, xmlhttprequest

I have an issue where I've created a Flask web server that I've hosted on Heroku which includes a function that stores a cookie in Chrome.

The function for storing the cookie is as follows:

```
@app.route('/api/v1.0/setcookie', methods=['GET'])
def setcookie():
    series = str(np.random.randint(10**8, 10**9))
    token = str(np.random.randint(10**8, 10**9)).encode('utf-8')
    hashed_token = hashlib.sha256(token).hexdigest()
    resp = make_response()
    resp.set_cookie('huga_series_id', series, max_age=60*60*24*365*5)
    resp.set_cookie('huga_series_token', token, max_age=60*60*24*365*5)
    cookies = mongo.db.cookies
    cookies.insert({'series': series, 
        'token': hashed_token})
    return resp
```

This function is part of a Flask web server, which is hosted at the URL https://my-server-name.herokuapp.com/.

Here is the problem: when I visit the URL https://my-server-name.herokuapp.com/api/v1.0/setcookie, the cookie is stored properly in my Chrome browser. However, if I try to submit a GET request to this URL from Javascript using XMLHTTTPREQUEST as follows:

```
    var xxhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xxhttp.open("GET", "https://my-server-name.herokuapp.com//api/v1.0/setcookie", true);
    xxhttp.send();
```

No cookies are stored. I've done testing and I'm confident that everything--the XMLHttpRequest sending, the Python code, etc. works. The only difference between these two methods is that I'm submitting a GET request through Javascript in one and manually visiting the URL in another.

Any ideas on how I can store cookies in Chrome using the XMLHttpRequest?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, try using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead.  If you must support old browsers too, use [this poly-fill](https://github.com/github/fetch#sending-cookies).  Your problem with XMLHttpRequest probably has something to do with not setting the path when you set the cookie (there are some unexpected rules on how this works).  Rather than trying to fix it using the old API, use the better Fetch API and read this [about setting cookies](https://github.com/github/fetch#sending-cookies).